Unable to get Call recording of online meeting using Microsoft Graph API
I am working on Microsoft graph Api to fetch recording of teams online Meeting and using behalf of user application.
The graph api I'm calling is - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Buser_id%7D/onlineMeetings/%7Bmeeting_id%7D/recordings
I have added the required permissions.
permissions
The code I'm running:
url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_id/onlineMeetings/{meeting_id}/recordings"



headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {bearer_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Make the GET request with the defined headers
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("User data retrieved successfully:")
    print(response.content)
else:
    print("Error occurred during user data retrieval:")
    print(response.text)
    print("Status Code:", response.status_code)

For getting access token:
data = {
    "client_id": client_id,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "scope": scope,
    "grant_type": grant_type
}

# Make the POST request
response = requests.post(url, data=data)

# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Token retrieved successfully:")
    # print(response.json())
else:
    print("Error occurred during token retrieval:")
    print(response.text)
bearer_token = response.json()["access_token"]

But I am getting error while calling Api.
{"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Application is not allowed to perform operations on the user {user_id}, neither is allowed access through RSC permission evaluation.","innerError":{"date":"2024-08-27T05:37:36","request-id":"request_id","client-request-id":"client_id"}}}

As suggested in documentation and previous solutions that we need to create application access policy and grant it to the user. I did the same
app access policy
Still getting same error
